# Checkbox in the popupMenu

Tags: java, android, checkbox, popupmenu

I have popupMenu and CheckBox. I need make write status CheckBox to boolean.
This code not working:

```
MenuItem fast_result;
boolean fast=false;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
            case R.id.FastResult:
                fast_result = item.getSubMenu().getItem(R.id.FastResult);//This is 182 line
                fast_result.setChecked(!fast_result.isChecked());
                fast=fast_result.isChecked();
                return true;
    }
}
```

It is errors:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.alexvsalex.HelpforMath.RootsActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(RootsActivity.java:182)
>               at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:163)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What to do?

Comment: well your getItem returns null so check whether the submenu or item exists

Comment: Item is missing. Why?

Comment: Do you get the items from a webservice call? If so, check the w/s response.

Comment: This application is offline.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved:

```
case R.id.FastResult:
            fast_result = item; //There was an error
            fast_result.setChecked(!fast_result.isChecked());
            fast=fast_result.isChecked();
            return true;
```